# Copy from Recordset into a new Workbook created on the fly

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to create a recordset with data in my workbook.  Then drop that recordset into a new workbook I created.  Am I barking up the wrong tree here, is it not possible because the recordset is out of scope of the new workbook? Help please?

```
Sub CopyWithADODB()
    ' Reference to: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
    Dim myConnection As String
    Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim mySQL As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Now As String
    Dim Server As String

    Server = "ServerX"

    Now = Date
    Now = "" & Server & "_" & Format(Now, "DD-MM-YYYY")
    Now = Replace(Now, "-", "_")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName


     myConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source='" & strPath & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"" "


        mySQL = "SELECT [d_pending$].[CustName],[d_pending$].[CustAddress] , [d_pending$].[CustTel], [d_pending$].[Email], [d_pending$].[Order], [d_pending$].[Loyalty] " & _
        "FROM [d_pending$]"


        Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
        RS.Open mySQL, myConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic



    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add
    wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").CopyFromRecordset RS

    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:="" & Now & ""
    wbTarget.Close SaveChanges:=False

    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi - `CopyFromRecordset` is a method of a range, not a worksheet. Try picking a cell in that worksheet then use the `CopyFromRecordset` method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset.  E.g. `wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset RS`

Comment: Fantastic!!  Thanks so much.  Works a treat.